# Using condition in tf2.1.0-keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.x

I am trying to using the bool condition in my own tf2.1.0-keras model, below is the simple example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class TestKeras:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def build_graph(self):
        x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(2),batch_size=1)
        x_value = x[0,0]
        y = tf.cond(x_value > 0, lambda :tf.add(x_value,0), lambda :tf.add(x_value,0))
        return tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[x], outputs=[y])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tk = TestKeras()
    model = tk.build_graph()
    model.summary(line_length=100)
```

but it seem not work and throw the exception:

```
using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.
```

I have try to replace the `tf.cond` with `tf.keras.backend.switch`, but it still got the same error.

Also i have try to split the code `y = tf.cond(xxx)` into a single funtion and add the `@tf.funcion` decorator:

```
@tf.function
def compute_y(self,x):
    return tf.cond(x > 0, lambda :tf.add(x,0), lambda :tf.add(x,0))
```

but it got another error:

```
Inputs to eager execution function cannot be Keras symbolic tensors, but found [<tf.Tensor 'strided_slice:0' shape=() dtype=float32>]
```

Anyone knows how can condition works in tf2.1.0-keras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.keras.Input` is a symbolic Tensor used to define an input for a keras model. Whenever you want to apply custom logic in a keras model, you should either subclass the `Layer` class, or use a `Lambda` layer.

For example, with a `Lambda` layer:

```
class TestKeras:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def build_graph(self):
        x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(2),batch_size=1)
        def custom_fct(x):
            x_value = x[0,0]
            return tf.cond(x_value > 0, lambda :tf.add(x_value,0), lambda :tf.add(x_value,0))
        y = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(custom_fct)(x)
        return tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[x], outputs=[y])
```